# Objective C - Detect mouse position without event

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

I'm an objective C noob and I'm making a 2d game that allows players to move a tank with the arrow keys, and aim the turret with the mouse.

Currently, the turret direction is updated (by the method below) using ccMouseMoved. This passes an `NSEvent` that can then very easily be converted (by convertEventToGL) into coordinates relative to the window (as opposed to relative to the screen). This all works, but it'd like to be able to make the method below update the turret direction when the tank is moved via the arrow keys (I.e. if the tank moves down, the turret will adjust to continue pointing towards the mouse cursor).

How can I achieve this?

```
-(BOOL) ccMouseMoved:(NSEvent *)event
{
    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
    int x = MAX(_player.position.x, winSize.width/2);
    int y = MAX(_player.position.y, winSize.height/2);
    x = MIN(x, (_tileMap.mapSize.width * _tileMap.tileSize.width) - winSize.width / 2);
    y = MIN(y, (_tileMap.mapSize.height * _tileMap.tileSize.height) - winSize.height/2);
    CGPoint actualPosition = ccp(x, y);

    CGPoint mousePosition = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertEventToGL:event];
    _playerTurret.rotation= -atan2((mousePosition.y - winSize.height/2 - _player.position.y + actualPosition.y),(mousePosition.x - winSize.width/2 - _player.position.x + actualPosition.x)) * 180/M_PI + 180;

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use the NSWindow method mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream.

[mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream)